# How to check if a value within a range is multiple of a value from another range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, rounding, date-range

Let say I've a system that distribute 8820 values into 96 values, rounding using Banker's Round (call them `pulse`). The formula is:

```
pulse = BankerRound(8820 * i/96), with i[0,96[
```

Thus, this is the list of pulses:

```
0
92
184
276
368
459
551
643
735
827
919
1011
1102
1194
1286
1378
1470
1562
1654
1746
1838
1929
2021
2113
2205
2297
2389
2481
2572
2664
2756
2848
2940
3032
3124
3216
3308
3399
3491
3583
3675
3767
3859
3951
4042
4134
4226
4318
4410
4502
4594
4686
4778
4869
4961
5053
5145
5237
5329
5421
5512
5604
5696
5788
5880
5972
6064
6156
6248
6339
6431
6523
6615
6707
6799
6891
6982
7074
7166
7258
7350
7442
7534
7626
7718
7809
7901
7993
8085
8177
8269
8361
8452
8544
8636
8728
```

Now, suppose the system doesn't send to me these pulses directly. Instead, it send these pulse in 8820th (call them `tick`):

```
tick = value * 1/8820
```

The list of the ticks I get become:

```
0
0.010430839
0.020861678
0.031292517
0.041723356
0.052040816
0.062471655
0.072902494
0.083333333
0.093764172
0.104195011
0.11462585
0.124943311
0.13537415
0.145804989
0.156235828
0.166666667
0.177097506
0.187528345
0.197959184
0.208390023
0.218707483
0.229138322
0.239569161
0.25
0.260430839
0.270861678
0.281292517
0.291609977
0.302040816
0.312471655
0.322902494
0.333333333
0.343764172
0.354195011
0.36462585
0.375056689
0.38537415
0.395804989
0.406235828
0.416666667
0.427097506
0.437528345
0.447959184
0.458276644
0.468707483
0.479138322
0.489569161
0.5
0.510430839
0.520861678
0.531292517
0.541723356
0.552040816
0.562471655
0.572902494
0.583333333
0.593764172
0.604195011
0.61462585
0.624943311
0.63537415
0.645804989
0.656235828
0.666666667
0.677097506
0.687528345
0.697959184
0.708390023
0.718707483
0.729138322
0.739569161
0.75
0.760430839
0.770861678
0.781292517
0.791609977
0.802040816
0.812471655
0.822902494
0.833333333
0.843764172
0.854195011
0.86462585
0.875056689
0.88537415
0.895804989
0.906235828
0.916666667
0.927097506
0.937528345
0.947959184
0.958276644
0.968707483
0.979138322
0.989569161
```

Unfortunately, between these ticks it sends to me also `fake ticks`, that aren't multiply of original `pulses`. Such as `0,029024943`, which is multiply of `256`, which isn't in the pulse lists.

How can I find from this list which ticks are `valid` and which are `fake`?
I don't have the pulse list to compare with during the process, since `8820` will change during the time, so I don't have a list to compare step by step. I need to deduce it from ticks at each iteration.

What's the best math approch to this? Maybe reasoning only in tick and not pulse.

I've thought to find the closer error between nearest integer pulse and prev/next tick. [Here](http://cpp.sh/2vl7f) in C++:

```
double pulse = tick * 96.;
double prevpulse = (tick - 1/8820.) * 96.;
double nextpulse = (tick + 1/8820.) * 96.;

int pulseRounded=round(pulse);
int buffer=lrint(tick * 8820.);

double pulseABS = abs(pulse - pulseRounded);
double prevpulseABS = abs(prevpulse - pulseRounded);
double nextpulseABS = abs(nextpulse - pulseRounded);

if (nextpulseABS > pulseABS && prevpulseABS > pulseABS) {
    // is pulse
}
```

but for example tick `0.0417234` (pulse `368`) fails since the prev tick error seems to be closer than it: `prevpulseABS` error (`0.00543795`) is smaller than `pulseABS` error (`0.0054464`).

That's because this comparison doesn't care about rounding I guess.

Comment: Why not just store all the pulse values in the list and when system sends you a value search for it in the list?

Comment: Could you simplify this example to deal with say six values rather than 96?  Also note that SO uses English, and the decimal separator is ".", not ",".

Comment: The pulse list its not a fixed list that I can check and compare. 8820 can vary due the time, thus ticks and pulse. The only real fixed value are ticks.

Comment: perhaps reduce the problem into an easily compilable complete program, using some example data in the array, an example input and an assert to assert the result you want? Then perhaps we can help you without risking being flamed and downvoted.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I give to you example data. What do you need more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RichardHodges: here you can test it http://cpp.sh/2vl7f

Comment: @markzzz So actually, you are calculating `round(x * i / 96.0) / x`, with a varying x? Is there any way to know or predict about how x changes?

Comment: it sounds like you have to check if `tick*96` is integer

Comment: @Aconcagua: no, its dynamic. 8820 means 8820 values per beat at 300 bpm (so, 44100 values at seconds). I continuously change tempo during the time. tick values are independent from time.

Comment: @KarstenKoop: what do you mean with "is integer"? `0,0417234 * 96 = 4,0054464` is not integer. `0,0520408 * 96 = 4,9959168` the same, not integer, but both are expected values.

Comment: @markzzz Problem is rounding. If you vary x, 8820 or whatever you call it, the rounding error can change and thus the ticks can, too.

Comment: The system who give to me the values are accounting rouding problem, giving to me the ticks already rounded at the current tempo. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW POST:**

Alright. Based on what I now understand, here's my revised answer.

You have the information you need to build a list of good values. Each time you switch to a new track:

```
vector<double> good_list;
good_list.reserve(96);
for(int i = 0; i < 96; i++)
    good_list.push_back(BankerRound(8820.0 * i / 96.0) / 8820.0);
```

Then, each time you want to validate the input:

```
auto iter = find(good_list.begin(), good_list.end(), input);
if(iter != good_list.end()) //It's a match!
    cout << "Happy days! It's a match!" << endl;
else
    cout << "Oh bother. It's not a match." << endl;
```

The problem with mathematically determining the correct pulses is the BankerRound() function which will introduce an ever-growing error the higher values you input. You would then need a formula for a formula, and that's getting out of my wheelhouse. Or, you could keep track of the differences between successive values. Most of them would be the same. You'd only have to check between two possible errors. But that falls apart if you can jump tracks or jump around in one track.

**OLD POST:**

If I understand the question right, the only information you're getting should be coming in the form of (p/v = y) where you know 'y' (that's each element in your list of ticks you get from the device) and you know that 'p' is the Pulse and 'v' is the Values per Beat, but you don't know what either of them are. So, pulling one point of data from your post, you might have an equation like this:

p/v = 0.010430839

'v', in all the examples you've used thus far, is 8820, but from what I understand, that value is not a guaranteed constant. The next question then is: Do you have a way of determining what 'v' is before you start getting all these decimal values? If you do, you can work out mathematically what the smallest error can be (1/v) then take your decimal information, multiply it by 'v', round it to the nearest whole number and check to see if the difference between its rounded form and its non-rounded form falls in the bounds of your calculated error like so:

```
double input; //let input be elements in your list of doubles, such as 0.010430839
double allowed_error = 1.0 / values_per_beat;
double proposed = input * values_per_beat;
double rounded = std::round(proposed);
if(abs(rounded - proposed) < allowed_error){cout << "It's good!" << endl;}
```

If, however, you are *not* able to ascertain the values_per_beat ahead of time, then this becomes a statistical question. You must accumulate enough data samples, remove the outliers (the few that vary from the norm) and use that data. But that approach will not be realtime, which, given the terms you've been using (values per beat, bpm, the value 44100) it sounds like realtime might be what you're after.

Comment: I can get values_per_beat at each iteration, so I'm ok with this. It's that "round" that afraid me.

Comment: Using your 8820 as values_per_beat, then, here's an example of why this will work. 1/8820 is the amount the decimal can be different for it to be considered a different value (as 93/8820 - 92/8820 = 1/8820).

Comment: Not sure what I'm wrong with your code: http://cpp.sh/2hlei but here no one values works :(

Comment: Maybe you are missing somethings inside allowed_error? With your code actually, there is no informations about I'm "scaling" to a 1/96 system.

Comment: In your OP, is the 96 in "pulse = BankerRound(8820 * i/96), with i[0,96[" known/fixed?

Comment: The rounding can vary, so having just a floor for each 1/96, or Round to Even. That's why I would base my count on just the tick (which already take account of this approximation) I get.

Comment: In less word: I also need to understand from the tick itself (and it's offset from a non rounding value) if it's a ppq previously rounded with floor or round to even.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to do a bit of statistical analysis, then. You can figure out what the pulse is, but without knowing what the pulse should be related to (i.e. 96) you can't check ahead of time.
You could, I suppose, keep track of them and take the most common occurring value and use that going forward, assuming that '96' value doesn't change at runtime. You'd just have to have a 'calibration' period as it analyzed the information coming in and used a statistical analysis approach to figure out what that '96' is supposed to be.

Comment: No no! 96 is always costant! Is the value I'm looking for :) Each beat (8820 samples) is always divided into 96.

Comment: ... If 96 is constant and you can find out what the samples value is ahead of time and you're supposed to be getting this data in order, then it's simple.

Keep track of which sample you're on (1, 2, 3, etc...) and feed that into your formula above (BankersRounding(sample_value * i / 96) / sample_value) to get what the value should be. If it equals your input, it's valid. if it's not, it's not. Increment your counter if it's valid and don't if it's not (assuming errant values are inserted and not overriding good values). Once your counter reaches 96, roll it over to 1 again.

Comment: Its not sure that data is received in order. For example, I can manually switch to another position during the "track", getting ppq (tick) at that position.

Comment: So you're on track A, tick 32, then you switch to track B. Will your next tick be 33 or will it reset to 1 (or some unpredictable number)? And no matter the track, it'll be out of 96, right? Regardless, if 96 is constant across all tracks, all valid pulses should be multiples of (BankerRound(sample_value/96)/sample_value). If they're not (with perhaps a little bit of leeway for rounding errors as computers do) then it's not a valid pulse.

Comment: The tick will be at the place I'll positioning the cursor over the track :) So I can swtich from 0.0416100 (367, not valid) to 0.406236 (3583, valid).

Comment: But you can still verify it by seeing if it's a multiple of (BankerRound(sample_value/96)/sample_value).

Comment: That's the task :) Verify if the tick is multiple or not

Answer (score 0):

I assume your initializing your pulses in a for-loop, using `int i` as loop variable; then the problem is this line:

```cpp
BankerRound(8820 * i/96);
```

`8820 * i / 96` is an all integer operation and the result is integer again, cutting off the remainder (so in effect, always rounding towards zero already), and BankerRound actually has nothing to round any more. Try this instead:

```cpp
BankerRound(8820 * i / 96.0);
```

Same problem applies if you are trying to calculate prev and next pulse, as you actually subtract and add 0 (again, `1/8820` is all integer and results in 0).

**Edit:**

From what I read from the commments, the 'system' is not – as I assumed previously – modifiable. Actually, it calculates ticks in the form of

```
n / 96.0, n &#x220a [0, 96) in ℕ
```

however including some kind of internal rounding appearently independent from the sample frequency, so there is some difference to the true value of n/96.0 and the ticks multiplied by 96 do not deliver exactly the integral values in [0, 96) (thanks KarstenKoop). And some of the delivered samples are simply invalid...

So the task is to detect, if tick * 96 is close enough to an integral value to be accepted as valid.

So we need to check:

```cpp
double value = tick * 96.0;
bool isValid
    =  value - floor(value) < threshold
    || ceil(value) - value  < threshold;
```

with some appropriately defined threshold. Assuming the values really are calculated as

```cpp
double tick = round(8820*i/96.0)/8820.0;
```

then the maximal deviation would be slightly greater than 0.00544 (see below for a more exact value), thresholds somewhere in the sizes of 0.006, 0.0055, 0.00545, ... might be a choice.

Rounding might be a matter of internally used number of bits for the sensor value (if we have 13 bits available, ticks might actually be calculated as `floor(8192 * i / 96.0) / 8192.0` with 8192 being `1 << 13` &ndash and floor accounting to integer division; just a guess...).

The exact value of the maximal deviation, using 8820 as factor, as exact as representable by double, was:
0.00544217687075132516838493756949901580810546875

The multiplication by 96 is actually not necessary, you can compare directly with the threshold divided by 96, which would be:
0.0000566893424036596371706764330156147480010986328125

Comment: I don't init anything. Read well the question: I don't have the pulse list. I derived it from ticks. Which is dynamic (i.e. 8820 change during the time). So I don't have any fixed pulse list. Of course I'm rounding a double, that was just an example.

Comment: This was unclear from your question, seemed to me as if you were programming the server, too, and it was delivering bad values due to bad calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with Excel, I think you want to multiply up to (what should be) whole numbers rather than looking for closest pulses.

```
Tick                Pulse                   i   Error                           OK
                Tick*8820       Pulse*96/8820   ABS( i - INT( i+0.05 ) )    Error < 0.01
------------    ------------    -------------   ------------------------    ------------
0.029024943     255.9999973     2.786394528     0.786394528                 FALSE
0.0417234       368.000388      4.0054464       0.0054464                   TRUE
0                 0             0               0                           TRUE
0.010430839      91.99999998    1.001360544     0.001360544                 TRUE
0.020861678     184             2.002721088     0.002721088                 TRUE
0.031292517     275.9999999     3.004081632     0.004081632                 TRUE
0.041723356     367.9999999     4.005442176     0.005442176                 TRUE
0.052040816     458.9999971     4.995918336     0.004081664                 TRUE
0.062471655     550.9999971     5.99727888      0.00272112                  TRUE
0.072902494     642.9999971     6.998639424     0.001360576                 TRUE
0.083333333     734.9999971     7.999999968     3.2E-08                     TRUE
```

The table shows your two "problem" cases (the real wrong value, 256, and the one your code gets wrong, 368) followed by the first few "good" values.

If both `8820`s vary at the same time, then obviously they will cancel out, and `i` will just be `Tick*96`.

The `Error` term is the difference between the calculated `i` and the nearest integer; if this less than `0.01`, then it is a "good" value.

NOTE: the `0.05` and `0.01` values were chosen somewhat arbitrarily (aka inspired first time guess based on the numbers): adjust if needed.  Although I've only shown the first few rows, all the 96 "good" values you gave show as TRUE.

The code (completely untested) would be something like:

```
double pulse = tick * 8820.0 ;
double i = pulse * 96.0 / 8820.0 ;
double error = abs( i - floor( i + 0.05 ) ) ;
if( error < 0.05 ) {
    // is pulse
}
```

Comment: The problem is when you have "near" values. Let says I get from the system the tick `0.0418367` (pulse 369). The error is smaller, such as 368 and 0.0417234. But that value need to be ignored.

Comment: Just plugged `0.0418367` in and it gives FALSE (where as `0.0417234` gives TRUE).  If you've got a spreadsheet handy, it might be worth plugging in the numbers as I did and have a play.  Even if `0.05` and `0.01` aren't perfect, the technique should be sound.

Comment: It fails with tick `0.406349` (3584): http://cpp.sh/62rth . 3584 is not pulse, 3583 is